# Password decrypter Failing

Tags: python, cryptography, aes

Good day,

I have a script I'm creating that reads user input and compares it to the key saved in a text file. It fails even if the strings are the same please help me:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from tkinter import *
#create the window
root = Tk()

#modify root window
root.title("Button Example")
#root.geometry("500x500")

app = Frame(root)
key='Key is unique!!!'
IV='This is an IV456'
#password=b'\xa3Y\x00\xae\xad\xad\x1c\xc6Js\xa9\xf4\x0e\xf3\x0f\xe3'


def encrypt():
    obj = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
    messagein = inputbar.get()
    inputbar.delete(0,END)
    messlen = len(messagein)
    if messlen < 16:
        diff = 16-messlen
        message = 'z'*diff + messagein
    global ciphertext
    ciphertext = obj.encrypt(message)
    print(ciphertext)
    del obj
def check():
    encrypt()
    passwordfunc()
    if ciphertext == password:
        print('Success!')
    else:
        print('Fail!')

def passwordfunc():
    file=open("E536D.dat","r")
    global password
    password = file.readline()
    file.close() 
    print(password)

inputbar = Entry(root,font='TkDefaultFont 30')
inputbar.pack()

button1= Button(text='Encrpyt',command=lambda:encrypt())
button1.pack()
button2 = Button(text='Compare',command=lambda:check())
button2.pack()
button3 = Button(text='File',command=lambda:passwordfunc())
button3.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

What have I done wrong? The line `#password=b'\xa3Y\x00\xae\xad\xad\x1c\xc6Js\xa9\xf4\x0e\xf3\x0f\xe3'` is the key it needs to compare to but it returns false for the comparison from the file but inside itself it works. Please help me. I fixed the different key output by moving `obj = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)` into encrypt and deleting it at the end of the function. But when I compare the string from the file and the correct input python still says they not the same. Below is a screenshot of what I mean.
[image]

Comment: the key and the IV must have 16 characters, and the text to be encripted must be a multiple of 16 characters , you have to pad it with some character like whitespace if it's not

Comment: I did thats what this does: `if messlen < 16:
        diff = 16-messlen
        message = 'z'*diff + messagein`

Comment: Is "E536D.dat" a binary file containing _just_ those bytes, with no newline? If so, you should open it in binary mode and use the `.read()` method to get the byte data. If it's not, you should show us a hex dump of its contents so we can figure out how to read it properly.

Comment: "E536D.dat" is just a plain text file containing the key b'\xa3Y\x00\xae\xad\xad\x1c\xc6Js\xa9\xf4\x0e\xf3\x0f\xe3' I have added a screenshot. Take a look at what I mean. The first Print is the cyperkeytext the second is the line read from "E536D.dat" and the last print is when it compared cyperkeytext with the line from "E536D.dat"

Comment: Ok. Does this code `print(repr(open("E536D.dat").read()))` print this: `"b'\\xa3Y\\x00\\xae\\xad\\xad\\x1c\\xc6Js\\xa9\\xf4\\x0e\\xf3\\x0f\\xe3'"` ?

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gains access he will also get the encryption key. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: If you have Python 3.4+, there's a PBKDF2 in the standard library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/hashlib.html#key-derivation

Comment: In future, you should try to condense your question code into a [mcve] that focuses on your problem. That Tkinter stuff is mostly an irrelevant distraction.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I have fixed it. The problem was that ciphertext was in bytes and my file had it read as a string so I did the below and wrote it to a file using bytes and reading it as bytes now it works 100%

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from tkinter import *
#create the window
root = Tk()

#modify root window
root.title("Button Example")
#root.geometry("500x500")

app = Frame(root)
key='Key is unique!!!'
IV='This is an IV456'
#password=b'\xa3Y\x00\xae\xad\xad\x1c\xc6Js\xa9\xf4\x0e\xf3\x0f\xe3'


def encrypt():
    obj = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, IV)
    messagein = inputbar.get()
    inputbar.delete(0,END)
    messlen = len(messagein)
    if messlen < 16:
        diff = 16-messlen
        message = 'z'*diff + messagein
    global ciphertext
    ciphertext = obj.encrypt(message)
    del obj

def passwordfunc():
    file=open("E536D.dat","rb")
    global password
    password = file.readline()
    file.close()

def check():
    encrypt()
    passwordfunc()
    print('ciphertext = ',ciphertext)
    print('  password = ',password)
    if ciphertext == password:
        print('Success!')
    else:
        print('Fail!')

def write():
    encrypt()
    file=open("E536D.dat","wb")
    file.write(ciphertext) 
    file.close()


inputbar = Entry(root,font='TkDefaultFont 30')
inputbar.pack()

button1= Button(text='Encrpyt',command=lambda:encrypt())
button1.pack()
button2 = Button(text='Compare',command=lambda:check())
button2.pack()
button3 = Button(text='File',command=lambda:passwordfunc())
button3.pack()
button4 = Button(text='Write',command=lambda:write())
button4.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks to ***PM 2RIng*** for your help. Your question had me thinking so I managed to get it fixed with a quick google. Thanks so much

Comment: Writing and reading the bytes as bytes is the sensible solution. :) For future reference, it _is_ possible to convert a string representation of a bytes object into a proper bytes object by using `ast.literal_eval()`, but it's much better to avoid that extra level of complication.

Comment: If you must encrypt (don't really need passwords to be secure), use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to be secret. Of course the next issue is how to keep the encryption key secure, that is generally not easy.